# Image not being saved with PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a really simple HTML page with an image upload form as follows:

```
<form id="file_data">
    <input type='file' id='image_uploaded' accept='image'/>
    <input type='submit' id="upload_image"/>
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[id='file_data']").submit(function() {
        var form_data = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`upload.php` is creating a directory to store images, if the directory does not already exists. Then is supposed to store image in the directory:

```
<?php
    define("IMAGE_DIRECTORY", "images");

    //If the directory for images does not exist, create it
    if(!is_dir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)) {
        mkdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, 0777, true);
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tmp_name"], IMAGE_DIRECTORY . "\\" .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
?>
```

While the PHP script will create the directory, if it does not already exist, it is not saving any images to the directory. I'm assuming I am not accessing the image correctly from PHP, but the tutorials I've looked at don't explain too much of the details of what is actually going on when an image is sent in an Ajax call to PHP.

Comment: Your file input seems to be lacking a name attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem you are missing in code:

**Html**: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on `form` to upload file, also `<input type="file"` missing `name="file"`

**Php**: `move_uploaded_file` is not correct you are missing `['file']` for tmp_name `$_FILES['file']["tmp_name"]`

**Ajax**: `dataType:"html"` is missing so that your ajax get response as string from server

Update your **Html**, **Php** and **Ajax** code like this:

**Html Code:**

```
<form id="file_data" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type='file' name='file' id='image_uploaded' accept='image'/>
    <input type='submit' id="upload_image"/>
</form>
```

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
    define("IMAGE_DIRECTORY", "images");

    //If the directory for images does not exist, create it
    if(!is_dir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)) {
        mkdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, 0777, true);
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']["tmp_name"], IMAGE_DIRECTORY . "\\" .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
?>
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "upload.php", 
    data : form_data, 
    type : "POST", 
    async: false, 
    cache: false, 
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false, 
    dateType : "html", 
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: You can mark this answer as helpful, if it works for you so that it helps others as well.Thanks

Comment: I tried echoing the `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']["tmp_name"], IMAGE_DIRECTORY . "\\" .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));` to display it with an alert upon success or failure in the Ajax call but nothing is echoed

Comment: Actually, I tried just using `alert("FINISHED");` in the `success` and `failure` methods of the Ajax call and the alert never occurs

Comment: ok you also have error in your ajax code, let me update my answer